# quatre cent quatre vingt quarante et quatre

Tags: sens, nombres

Dans le roman Pantagruel de Rabelais, l'auteur a écrit : [Gargantua, en son eage de quatre cens quatre vingtz quarante  et quatre ans...](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Pantagruel/%C3%89dition_Marty-Laveaux,_1868/Chapitre_2)  Je me demande la signification de ce « quatre cent quatre vingt quarante et quatre », c’est combien ce nombre ? 
Est-ce que ça veut dire 524 (400+80+40+4), si c’est le cas, pourquoi on ne dit pas cinq cent vingt quatre ?
S’il représente un autre nombre, comment on peut décomposer cette expression ?

Comment: My guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigesimal

Answer (score 3):

Tu as absolument raison. Ta transcription ainsi que le calcul sont absolument corrects.

Ce nombre est effectivement et, même pour l'époque, présenté de façon **bizarre**.
Au point que nombreux sont ceux qui se sont précipités pour y lire une signification cachée.
Il faut savoir que Rabelais a toujours soigneusement évité de dater les événements qu'il relate. Mais à la vérité, ils le sont, mais de façon cachée et symbolique, le tout présenté de façon volontairement embrouillée.

Johanneau in *Mémoires de la société des sciences, arts et belles lettres* suggère de retrancher 500 à cette somme pour obtenir 24 qui correspond à l'âge qu'avait François I en 1518 date retenue pour l'écriture de l'*oeuvre*.